# AngularJS directive - initial invoke function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use this directive:

```
function communicationCreateFormDirective($timeout) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            selectedCommunicationGroups: '=',
            currentUser: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/communication/....html',
        link: function($scope) {
            ...
            connect();
```

and I will initially invoke the function connect() but I get the error:

```
angular.js:14110 ReferenceError: connect is not defined
```

Also **$scope.connect()** does not work. Does anyone know how to do?

Thats the function:

```
$scope.connect = function() {
                var socket = new SockJS('/api/chat');
                $scope.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);            
                $scope.stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                    console.log('webSocket Connected in communicationCreateForm.directive.js: ' + frame);
                    $scope.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/communication/' + $scope.currentUser.id, function(message) {
                        //vm.showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body));
                        alert('Message response QUMA: ' + JSON.parse(message.body));
                    });
                });
            }
```

Comment: Well... That's usually what happen when you're calling an undefined function

Comment: Does the `$scope.connect` function defined outside of the directive scope (In another controller?) Then you should bind it to the directive by changing its `scope: { ... }` object, and add: `connect: '&'`. Then you should be able to invoke the function from the directive using `$scope.connect()` (But don't forget to bind it to the directive in the view using a `connect="connect()"` attribute!)

Answer (score 1):

Your directive is creating a new isolated scope which does not have direct access to the scope of the controller in which you defined connect. You need to pass in the function similar to how you are passing in `selectedCommunicationGroups` and `currentUser` for it to be in your link function's scope.

```
function communicationCreateFormDirective($timeout) {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      selectedCommunicationGroups: '=',
      currentUser: '=',
      connect: '=' // <- "links" the scopes together
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/communication/....html',
    link: function($scope) {
      ...
      $scope.connect();
```

HTML: `<wheverYouCalledIt connect="connect" ... >`

You can also use `'&'` instead of `'='` for connect, this would allow to you pass more thing along when calling the function, but doesn't look like you need that. If you did this, the HTML attribute would change slightly to be `connect="connect()"`

Comment: No, AFAIK you bind functions to a directive using `'&'` and not `'='`

Comment: @AlonEitan I added a note. '&' is meant to allow you to pass more thing in the call (such as local parameters). It's how `$event` gets there on your `ngClick`s and such. Either way works in this case.

Comment: Then you need to define it before you try to use it.